# Error in Assembly masm linker 'link: extra operand'

Tags: assembly, linker, linker-errors, masm32

I installed masm for assembly programming but i have problem with link below code

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK 4096
INCLUDE io.h

.DATA
prompt      BYTE "shalgham", 0

.CODE
_main       PROC
            output  prompt

            mov     eax, 0
            ret
_main       ENDP
END
```

when i assemble above code by commandLine every thing is ok
but when i want to link it below error will be print in commandLine

```
C:\Users\mahdi\Desktop\New folder>ml /c /coff simple.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: simple.asm

C:\Users\mahdi\Desktop\New folder>link /subsystem:console /entry:main simple.obj
 io.obj Kernel32.Lib
link: extra operand `simple.obj'
Try `link --help' for more information.
```

And when i use visual studio 2010 below error will be printed.

```
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\console32.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>_MASM:
1>  Assembling [Inputs]...
1>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
1>Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>temp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol itoaproc
1>temp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol atoiproc
1>temp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol dtoaproc
1>temp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol atodproc
1>temp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol inproc
1>temp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol outproc referenced in function _main
1>E:\programming\assembly\VS2010_files\console32\Debug\console32.exe : fatal error LNK1120:     6 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:06.14
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

before asking this question i search it very but not solution found

Comment: It looks like you've got a copy of GNU `link` somewhere in your PATH that is being used instead of Microsoft's `link`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this question was answered by @Michael, I would like to make it clear.

We have to put the CYGWIN path stand behind the MS Visual Studio path.

```
 Path=....C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\bin;C:\cygwin\bin
```

Open Windows command prompt:

```
cmd
link --help
```

Make sure:

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 6.00.8168
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.
```